# Create order for Customer Group

Tags: orders, customer-group, programmatically, admin-order-create

Let's say I want to send my best customers a free sticker. I have all my best customers in a group aptly named Best Customers. Are there any extensions or programatic ways to create an order of one sticker for all customers in Best Customers?

Maybe I could modify this solution to fit my needs, but I'm not sure how. Any ideas?

[Inchoo Programmatically create order](http://inchoo.net/magento/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/)

Comment: what is sticker order? do you mean order?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to first get the customers of that group whatever id the group has:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('group_id', 4);
```

then after you created the order(the link you mentioned somehow), you should assign each order to each customer in a loop like, create this order, assign this customer to order

```
 $order->setCustomerId($Customer->getId());
 $order->setCustomerFirstname($Customer->getFirstname()); 
$orderbyid->setCustomerLastname($Customer->getLastname());
$orderbyid->setCustomerEmail($Customer->getEmail());
$orderbyid->save();
```

also there are many extension for assign order to customers, it might not be exactly for customer groups